# Fullpage JS - navigation dots don't change in size on scroll

Tags: fullpage.js

Fullpage js navigation dots don’t change in size as I scroll between sections. Other navigation interactions work fine: the dots increase in size on hover and they are linked/anchored to the appropriate sections.

How can I make the dots change in size upon section transition? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The default navigation bullets change size as you can see [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html#secondPage). So unless you provide us with an codepen or jsfiiddle where we can't see this, my best guess is that you are not importing the CSS file or you are overwriting it's styles somehow.